# Mysql not working on mac Sierra after upgrading php

Tags: php, mysql, macos, laravel-valet

I recently upgraded my laravel valet to version 2 which installed php 7.2 through brew.  I had previously been on php 7.1.  I ran into a few bumps but got php and valet working but once I did I noticed mysql is no longer working.  If I do brew services start mysql it shows successful but if I type `mysql -v` I get the following error message.  `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

If I type `mysql.server start` I get the following error message

```
./usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.17_1/bin/mysqld_safe: line 674: /Users/swany/.valet/Log/mysql.log: No such file or directory
2019-09-11T17:24:54.6NZ mysqld_safe error: log-error set to '/Users/swany/.valet/Log/mysql.log', however file don't exists. Create writable for user 'mysql'.
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.17_1/bin/mysqld_safe: line 144: /Users/swany/.valet/Log/mysql.log: No such file or directory
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local.pid).
```

I have seen others with similar issues but when i walked through some of the solutions they didn't seem to work for me.  I am hoping to be able to save all my databases I already have when mysql was running.  I didn't try to upgrade mysql but it may tried as part of the valet upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there is a mysql process still running. Run the following command:

`ps aux | grep -i mysql`

If you see any processes running then kill them using the

`kill -9 PID`

Where PID = Process ID of the MySQL process.

After the processes have been terminated, try restarting mysql and see if this solved your problem.

Comment: when I run ps -aux | grep -i mysql I get this message ps: No user named 'x'

Comment: @Chris what about ps aux | grep -i mysql? I have updated my answer to reflect this change.

Comment: There was a process running with PID 417.  When I did kill 417 I got not permitted so I did sudo kill 417 and didn't give any message.  When I did ps aux | grep -i mysql the process was still running.

Comment: It is possible that you have mysql running as a service. Try stopping the service with this command: ```sudo service mysql stop```

Comment: I get unknown command service.  I did do brew services stop mysql and it acted like it stopped it.  Then I tried to kill 417 again with no luck as it still shows it is running.

Comment: Ah, try the command ```brew services stop mysql``` or you can also try the command ```/usr/local/bin/mysql.server stop```

Comment: Brew command I already ran and when ran again it states it is not running.  When I did the other one it states MYSQL server PID could not be found.  Here is what I show when i do the ps aux command.  _mysql             417   0.0  0.9  2672068 150848   ??  Us    1:07PM   0:00.29 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199328/discussion-between-chris-and-medium).